# Alternative to Application.DelayInitialize for Delphi 7 Service?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dcom

Is there an alternative to Application.DelayInitialize for Delphi 7?  I'm trying to create a Delphi 7 Service that hosts a COM Server but it doesn't work and I believe it is because I'm not using Application.DelayInitialize.

[Re: Windows Service / DelayInitialize](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.rtl/201011/1011144185.html)

Comment: *I believe that my service needs to do X. It does not do X. Is there an alternative to doing X?* Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: Beyond that, how did you diagnose the problem. Can you state clearly what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have written several COM-hosting services using BCB6, and they all work fine in all Windows versions from Win9x onwards, so I have had to deal with this same issue many times.

Simply don't call `Application.Initialize()` at process startup on Win2003+, wait until the `TService`'s `OnStart` or `OnExecute` event to call it. That way, the service API is running before any COM objects are initialized.

The trick is to delay the call to `Application.Initialize()` ONLY on Win2003+ and ONLY when the service is actually running.  DO NOT delay the call if *either*:

1. The service is running on Windows versions earlier than 2003.
2. when the service is being (un)installed.
3. when the COM object is being (un)registered.

Under those conditions, call `Application.Initialize()` normally at process startup.

So, you will need to check the OS version and the command line parameters to know when to call `Application.Initialize()` correctly.